# PHP Google Push Notifications

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, push-notification

I've been doing research on how to use ((google push notifications)) with PHP, but there aren't many working examples/documentation out there...

I'm trying to get this to work on an internal network, that isn't opened to the outside, over HTTP.

I was able to get this to work over HTTPS from our outward facing domain, but the internal attempt is telling me in the Chrome Console that `"the API may no longer be used from insecure origins"`, which I found means it requires HTTPS.

Does anyone know of a possible workaround for this, to spoof the HTTPS, or to allow it to continue over HTTP? I understand google put this in place as a preventative measure for people with malicious intent, but that's not the case here, as it'll be for private use.

My HTML is just a button with an `onclick="notifyMe()"` event.

Script to request permission, and function to notify:

```
<script>
// request permission on page load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  if (!Notification) {
    alert('Desktop notifications not available in your browser. Try Chromium.'); 
    return;
  }

  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();
});

function notifyMe() {
  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();
  else {
    var notification = new Notification('Notification title', {
      icon: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png',
      body: "Hey there! You've been notified!",
    });

    notification.onclick = function () {
      window.open("http://example.com");      
    };

  }

}
</script>
```

JS file with Notification Options, and permissions:

```
'use strict';

var button = document.querySelector('button');
var input = document.querySelector('input');

var notify = function() {
  var options = {
    body: input.value,
    icon: 'icon.png',
    tag: 'foo',
    type: 'basic'
  };
  var n = new Notification('Greetings!', options);
  n.onclick = function() {
    console.log('Clicked.');
  };
  n.onclose = function() {
    console.log('Closed.');
  };
  n.onshow = function() {
    console.log('Shown.');
  };
};

button.onclick = function() {
  if (!('Notification' in window)) {
    alert('This browser does not support desktop notification');
  } else if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
    notify();
  } else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
    Notification.requestPermission(function(permission) {
      if (!('permission' in Notification)) {
        Notification.permission = permission;
      }
      if (permission === 'granted') {
        notify();
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing extensive research and testing on this, I found that it isn't possible to use the Google Chrome notifications without an HTTPS connection, even if it's on an internal network.

I've opted for setting up an SSL Cert, and that has resolved my problem.